# Handle click on back button of action bar react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am using stack navigator in my project , clicking on Action Bar back button takes me to previous screen, But I want to take it to some other screen on clicking of back button. If I navigate from screen 1 to screen 2 then pressing back button it will take to screen1, but I need to take it to screen3. Any help would be appreciated.

I am handling hardware back button press like this. Same thing I want to do with navigation back button

```
componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');                 
            return true; 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        BackAndroid.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", () => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('3page');
        })
    }
```

Comment: I have already done this, I have stated in my question. I want to handle the action bar back button which is up there on the header

Comment: static navigation = {headerRight: (<BTN />)}

Comment: Button is already there which comes by default, but I want to change its default behavior which is it goes to previous screen.

Comment: TwoScreen:
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        headerLeft: (<Button title='back' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ThreeScreen')}/>)
    });